# Not able to get value of clicked spinner item, instead I get the cursor value

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

I have an activity with four spinners, which are populated from a database. You can choose the attributes of different cars. Let's say we can choose the brand, then horse power etc.. First I wanted to test, if I get a value when I click on a spinner, but I always get the cursor value, instead of what I clicked on the spinner (e.g. Honda, BMW). I am searching for a couple days, I also know that I need something like "getString()" or/and "selectedItem". But sadly I am still unable to fix the problem. I would like to e.g. click on the spinner item "Honda" and the toast message should show "Honda". 
I hope someone can show me, where I have to put the necessary code. I tried it within the cursor and beneath. Here is my code. Thank you :-)

```
public class ChooseCar extends Activity {

private Spinner BrandSpinner, HorsePowerSpinner, FuelSpinner, TireSpinner;
private Button btnSearch;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;

SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
final static String MY_DATABASE_NAME = "car_directory";
final static String MY_DATABASE_TABLE = "cars";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.car_choice);

    LoadBrandSpinner();
    LoadHorsePowerSpinner();
    LoadFuelSpinner();
    LoadTireSpinner();
    addListenerOnButton();

}



public void LoadBrandSpinner(){
    myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor myCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT _id, brand FROM " + MY_DATABASE_TABLE + ";", null);        
    startManagingCursor(myCursor);

    BrandSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    myCursor.moveToFirst();


   SimpleCursorAdapter spinadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            myCursor,
            new String[] {"brand"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}); 

    spinadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    BrandSpinner.setAdapter(spinadapter);
    BrandSpinner.setPrompt(this.getResources().getString(R.string.ChooseBrand)); 
    BrandSpinner.setAdapter(spinadapter);
    BrandSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}


public void LoadHorsePowerSpinner(){// The same like the first spinner ;-)}

public void LoadFuelSpinner(){// The same like the first spinner ;-)}

public void LoadTireSpinner(){// The same like the first spinner ;-)}

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {
  Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The car is " +
      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
  // Do nothing.
}
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

BrandSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
HorsePowerSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
FuelSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
TireSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner4);

btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);

btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(ChooseCar.this,
                "OnClickListener : " + 
                "\nBrand : " +   String.valueOf(BrandSpinner.getSelectedItem()) +
                "\nHorsePower : " + String.valueOf(HorsePowerSpinner.getSelectedItem()) +
                "\nFuel : " + String.valueOf(FuelSpinner.getSelectedItem()) +
                "\nTire : " + String.valueOf(TireSpinner.getSelectedItem()),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
}}
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776552/android-how-to-get-selected-item-from-data-driven-spinner

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I saw that, too and tried to implement this. I put this in the SimpleCursorAdapter with no success. My problem is where I have to put the code. Beneath "BrandSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());" or in the cursor beneath "new int[] {android.R.id.text1}"? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Setting `MyOnItemSelectedListener` as the spinner's `OnItemSelectedListener` is correct.

In the `onItemSelected` method of `MyOnItemSelectedListener`, you should be able to call `parent.getSelectedItem()`, which gives you the `Cursor` object of the selected brand.

Once you have your `Cursor`, do

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand"))
```

to retrieve the car brand.

Comment: I know I'm so close to the solution and I know that you are right. But implementing it crashes my app, because I do it wrong. I followed your advice this way:    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The car is " +
          parent.getSelectedItem(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand"));

Answer (score 0):

```
    appCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(((AppCompatTextView) view).getText()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "NothingSelected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```